# Cache the results of an operation, when done again only scan the ones that changed

Tags: c#, caching

I am using a tool that one of my coworkers wrote that scans through a directory and adds a moniker to a solution file and .csproj files.

I am scanning a file that has  = "Some category" from a text file to set the monikers in the .sln file and .csproj file.

The thing is that the projects list has approximately 700 projects. I am changing the location of the solution and the projects accordingly but some projects that the solution had dependencies on do not have the same moniker as the solution file so Visual Studio throws some error loading the project files.

To fix this I have to fix the moniker in my text file and run the tool again but the tool scans everything, instead of just the files that changed.

Is there a way that I can cache the results and just scan what has changed? I think it will save me a lot of time when I re-run the tool to fix the monikers of the projects that were wrong. Here is the method marking the .csproj files.

```
internal static void MarkAllProjects()
        {
            const string assemblyOutputTypeForLibrary = "library";
            Dictionary<string, string> projectEntries = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            using (var stream = new System.IO.StreamReader(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("ProjectMarker.ProjectList.txt")))
            {
                while (stream.EndOfStream == false)
                {
                    string[] projectEntry = stream.ReadLine().Split(new char[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    if (projectEntry.Count() == 2 && projectEntries.ContainsKey(projectEntry[0]) == false)
                    {
                        projectEntries.Add(projectEntry[0], projectEntry[1]);
                    }
                }
            }

            Parallel.ForEach<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(projectEntries, projectEntry =>
            {
                var files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectoryRoot, projectEntry.Key, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                Parallel.ForEach<string>(files, file =>
                {
                    XDocument projectFileAsXml = XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText(file, Encoding.UTF8));
                    string markerElementIdentifier = string.Empty;
                    string postBuildEventIdentifier = string.Empty;
                    string assemblyNameIdentifier = string.Empty;
                    string propertyGroupIdentifier = string.Empty;
                    string assemblyOutputType = string.Empty;
                    string projectOutputType = string.Empty;

                    if (projectFileAsXml.Root.GetDefaultNamespace() != null && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(projectFileAsXml.Root.GetDefaultNamespace().NamespaceName) == false)
                    {
                        markerElementIdentifier = string.Concat("{", projectFileAsXml.Root.GetDefaultNamespace(), "}", "ItemDefinitionGroup");
                        postBuildEventIdentifier = string.Concat("{", projectFileAsXml.Root.GetDefaultNamespace(), "}", "PostBuildEvent");
                        assemblyNameIdentifier = string.Concat("{", projectFileAsXml.Root.GetDefaultNamespace(), "}", "AssemblyName");
                        propertyGroupIdentifier = string.Concat("{", projectFileAsXml.Root.GetDefaultNamespace(), "}", "PropertyGroup");
                        assemblyOutputType = string.Concat("{", projectFileAsXml.Root.GetDefaultNamespace(), "}", "OutputType");
                        projectOutputType = string.Concat("{", projectFileAsXml.Root.GetDefaultNamespace(), "}", "ProjectTypeGuids");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        markerElementIdentifier = "ItemDefinitionGroup";
                        postBuildEventIdentifier = "PostBuildEvent";
                        assemblyNameIdentifier = "AssemblyName";
                        propertyGroupIdentifier = "PropertyGroup";
                        assemblyOutputType = "OutputType";
                        projectOutputType = "ProjectTypeGuids";
                    }

                    if (projectFileAsXml.Root.Element(markerElementIdentifier) == null
                        || (projectFileAsXml.Root.Element(markerElementIdentifier) != null
                        && projectFileAsXml.Root.Element(markerElementIdentifier).Attribute("Label") == null))
                    {
                        projectFileAsXml.Root.Add(new XElement(markerElementIdentifier, new XAttribute("Label", projectEntry.Value)));

                        if (projectFileAsXml.Root.Descendants(assemblyOutputType).FirstOrDefault() != null
                            && projectFileAsXml.Root.Descendants(assemblyOutputType).First().Value.ToLower() == assemblyOutputTypeForLibrary
                            && projectFileAsXml.Root.Descendants(assemblyNameIdentifier).FirstOrDefault() != null
                            && projectFileAsXml.Root.Descendants(assemblyNameIdentifier).First().Value.Contains("Test") == false
                            && (projectFileAsXml.Root.Descendants(projectOutputType).FirstOrDefault() == null
                                || projectTypeGuidsToBeExcluded.Exists(item => projectFileAsXml.Root.Descendants(projectOutputType).First().Value.ToUpper().Contains(item)) == false))
                        {

                            string nugetPublishDirectory = string.Concat(targetDirectoryRoot, "\\NuGetPublishings\\", projectEntry.Value, "\\", projectFileAsXml.Root.Descendants(assemblyNameIdentifier).First().Value, "\\lib");
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(nugetPublishDirectory);

                            if (projectFileAsXml.Root.Descendants(postBuildEventIdentifier).FirstOrDefault() == null)
                            {
                                projectFileAsXml.Root.Add(new XElement(propertyGroupIdentifier,
                                    new XElement(postBuildEventIdentifier,
                                        string.Concat("copy \"$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)\" ", "\"$(SolutionDir)..\\NuGetPublishings\\", projectEntry.Value, "\\$(ProjectName)\\lib\\$(TargetFileName)\""))));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                projectFileAsXml.Root.Descendants(postBuildEventIdentifier).First().Value
                                    += Environment.NewLine + string.Concat("copy \"$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)\" ", "\"$(SolutionDir)..\\NuGetPublishings\\", projectEntry.Value, "\\$(ProjectName)\\lib\\$(TargetFileName)\"");
                            }
                        }

                        projectFileAsXml.Save(file);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Let me know if you need more clarification.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using .NET 4.0 and above.

Have you tried looking at .NET 4.0 [Caching system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997357.aspx)?

A good example to look at for caching using the ObjectCache is found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290935/Using-MemoryCache-in-Net-4-0)